# How to save a PySpark dataframe as a CSV with custom file name?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

Here is the spark DataFrame I want to save as a csv.

```
type(MyDataFrame)
--Output: <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
```

To save this as a CSV, I have the following code:

```
MyDataFrame.write.csv(csv_path, mode = 'overwrite', header = 'true')
```

When I save this, the file name is something like this:

```
part-0000-766dfdf-78fg-aa44-as3434rdfgfg-c000.csv
```

Is there a way I can give this a custom name while saving it? Like **"MyDataFrame.csv"**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same requirement.You can write to one path, and then change the file path. This is my solution.

```py
def write_to_hdfs_specify_path(df, spark, hdfs_path, file_name):
    """
    :param df: dataframe which you want to save
    :param spark: sparkSession
    :param hdfs_path: target path(shoul be not exises)
    :param file_name: csv file name
    :return: 
    """
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
    FileSystem = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
    Configuration = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", True).option("delimiter", "|").option("compression", "none").csv(hdfs_path)
    fs = FileSystem.get(Configuration())
    file = fs.globStatus(Path("%s/part*" % hdfs_path))[0].getPath().getName()
    full_path = "%s/%s" % (hdfs_path, file_name)
    result = fs.rename(Path("%s/%s" % (hdfs_path, file)), Path(full_path))
    return result
```

Comment: I am uploading it directly to S3, then on `file = fs.globStatus`,  getting this error `IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: s3a://my-bucket/2022/10, expected: file:///`. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 4):

No. That's how Spark work (at least for now). You'd have `MyDataFrame.csv` as a **directory name**, and under that directory, you'd have multiple files with the same format as `part-0000-766dfdf-78fg-aa44-as3434rdfgfg-c000.csv`, `part-0000-766dfdf-78fg-aa44-as3434rdfgfg-c001.csv` etc

It's not recommended, but if your data is small enough (arguably what is "small enough" here), you can always convert it to Pandas and save it to a single CSV file with any name you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

`.coalesce(1)` will guarantee that there is only 1 file but will not guarantee file name. Please use some temp directory to save it and than rename it and copy (using dbutils.fs functions if you use databricks or using FileUtil from Hadoop API).